# Critical dependency using MongoDB with Angular universal / webpack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, webpack, angular-universal

i'm getting some errors trying to require the mongodb package into my angular universal project.

I wonderd if anyone had a sollution for this, or know of somewere its been posted as im not able to find any.

Code taken from the webpack documentation:

```
var cache = {};
function importAll (r) {
  console.log("importing " +r);
  r.keys().forEach(key => cache[key] = r(key));
}

importAll(require.context('mongodb', true, /\.js$/));
```

Errors:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js
2997:23-30 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb \.js$
 @ ./server.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/require_optional/index.js
82:18-42 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/require_optional/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb-core/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb \.js$
 @ ./server.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/require_optional/index.js
90:20-44 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/require_optional/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb-core/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb \.js$
 @ ./server.ts

WARNING in ./node_modules/require_optional/index.js
97:35-67 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/require_optional/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb-core/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/mongodb \.js$
 @ ./server.ts
```

Webpack cfg file ///...................................................///

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    // This is our Express server for Dynamic universal
    server: './server.ts',
    // This is an example of Static prerendering (generative)
    prerender: './prerender.ts'
  },
  target: 'node',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    alias: {
      'pg-native': path.join(__dirname, 'aliases/pg-native.js'),
      'pgpass$': path.join(__dirname, 'aliases/pgpass.js'),
    }
  },
  // Make sure we include all node_modules etc
  externals: [/(node_modules|main\..*\.js)/m],
  output: {
    // Puts the output at the root of the dist folder
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'}
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?angular(\\|\/)core(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'), // location of your src
      {} // a map of your routes
    ),
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
  ]
}
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue yesterday trying out angular universal starter with mongoose. First, I tried by using ContextReplacementPlugin webpack plugin like in webpack.server.config.js.

```
new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      // fixes WARNING Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
      /(.+)?express(\\|\/)(.+)?/,
      path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      {}
    )
```

I added a plugin for each library in the warning (just changed 'express' in the regex with 'mongoose', 'mongodb', 'mongodb-core' and 'require_optional'). That removed the warnings, but the server failed right after starting with a strange error about some missing module (the module was named something like '.'). Most likely I was misusing the plugin, I'm not sure, but I was in no mood for digging anymore into that and I just tried out [webpack-node-externals](https://github.com/liady/webpack-node-externals) library which solved the warnings and let the server start smoothly again.

Hope that helps! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Stop bundling the server dependencies using the option `bundleDependencies` in `angular.json`